# Webview upload file in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, webview

How to realise uploading files in webview using jetpack compose with 34 sdk?

All what i found is deprecated methods or not actually for me, ima looking methods using mediastore api, with request permissons and also methods for low api

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.